# How to load batches of data in a recycler view using firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to know how to load more data in recylcer view using firestore.

```
 Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection("ie").limit(5);  
adapter=new InterviewAdapter(this,query);    
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

Adapter class looks like this:

```
public class InterviewAdapter extends FireStoreAdapter<InterviewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public interface OnInterviewSelectedListener {

    void onInterviewSelected(DocumentSnapshot interview);

}

private InterviewAdapter.OnInterviewSelectedListener mListener;

public InterviewAdapter(Query query, OnInterviewSelectedListener listener) {
    super(query);
    mListener = listener;
}

@Override
public InterviewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    return new InterviewAdapter.ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.ie, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(InterviewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(getSnapshot(position), mListener);
}

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView title,companyName,username,views,isHired;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        companyName= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.companyName);
        username= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
        views= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.views);
        isHired= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.isHired);
    }

    public void bind(final DocumentSnapshot snapshot,
                     final OnInterviewSelectedListener listener) {


        InterviewExperience experience;
        String companyName=snapshot.getString("companyName");
        boolean isHired=Boolean.valueOf(snapshot.getBoolean("isHired"));
        String username=snapshot.getString("username");
        long views=new Double(Double.valueOf(snapshot.getDouble("views"))).longValue();

        String id=snapshot.getId();


        String title=snapshot.getString("title");
        experience=new InterviewExperience(id,title,companyName,username,isHired,views,null,null);


        this.title.setText(experience.getTitle());
        this.companyName.setText("Company Name: "+experience.getCompanyName());
        this.isHired.setText("Hired: "+experience.isHired());
        this.views.setText("Views: "+experience.getViews()+"");
        this.username.setText("Created By: "+experience.getUsername());



        // Click listener
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onInterviewSelected(snapshot);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
}

public abstract class FireStoreAdapter<VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
    extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH>
    implements EventListener<QuerySnapshot> {

private static final String TAG = "FirestoreAdapter";

private Query mQuery;
private ListenerRegistration mRegistration;

private ArrayList<DocumentSnapshot> mSnapshots = new ArrayList<>();

public FireStoreAdapter(Query query) {
    mQuery = query;
}

@Override
public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
    if (e != null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onEvent:error", e);
        onError(e);
        return;
    }

    // Dispatch the event
    Log.d(TAG, "onEvent:numChanges:" + documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges().size());
    for (DocumentChange change : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
        switch (change.getType()) {
            case ADDED:
                onDocumentAdded(change);
                break;
            case MODIFIED:
                onDocumentModified(change);
                break;
            case REMOVED:
                onDocumentRemoved(change);
                break;
        }
    }

    onDataChanged();
}

public void startListening() {
    if (mQuery != null && mRegistration == null) {
        mRegistration = mQuery.addSnapshotListener(this);
    }
}

public void stopListening() {
    if (mRegistration != null) {
        mRegistration.remove();
        mRegistration = null;
    }

    mSnapshots.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void setQuery(Query query) {
    // Stop listening
    stopListening();

    // Clear existing data
    mSnapshots.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();

    // Listen to new query
    mQuery = query;
    startListening();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mSnapshots.size();
}

protected DocumentSnapshot getSnapshot(int index) {
    return mSnapshots.get(index);
}

protected void onDocumentAdded(DocumentChange change) {
    mSnapshots.add(change.getNewIndex(), change.getDocument());
    notifyItemInserted(change.getNewIndex());
}

protected void onDocumentModified(DocumentChange change) {
    if (change.getOldIndex() == change.getNewIndex()) {
        // Item changed but remained in same position
        mSnapshots.set(change.getOldIndex(), change.getDocument());
        notifyItemChanged(change.getOldIndex());
    } else {
        // Item changed and changed position
        mSnapshots.remove(change.getOldIndex());
        mSnapshots.add(change.getNewIndex(), change.getDocument());
        notifyItemMoved(change.getOldIndex(), change.getNewIndex());
    }
}

protected void onDocumentRemoved(DocumentChange change) {
    mSnapshots.remove(change.getOldIndex());
    notifyItemRemoved(change.getOldIndex());
}

protected void onError(FirebaseFirestoreException e) {};

protected void onDataChanged() {}
}
```

I used Firestore Adapter code which was given in samples of firestore documentation. Can anyone tell how to use the query object to load more data?

How to load the next 5 items in the recycler view when users scrolls to the end of the list?

Answer (score 2):

You can paginate your `Query`'s result using `Query`'s methods like, [`startAt()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#startAt(java.lang.Object...)), [`startAfter()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#startAfter(com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot)),  [`endAt()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#endAt(com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot)), [`endBefore()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#endBefore(com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot)) with a specified `DocumentSnapshot`.

If I considered your collection is called "interviews", you can add a method to your `FireStoreAdapter` like this:

```
private void paginate(final DocumentSnapshot last, final int limit) {
    final Query subset;
    if (last == null) {
        subset = db.collection("interviews")
                .limit(limit);
    } else {
        subset = db.collection("interviews")
                .startAfter(last)
                .limit(limit);
    }
    setQuery(subset);
}
```

You can perserve the last `DocumentSnapshot` within `onEvent()`:

```
final List<DocumentChange> changes = documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges();
final DocumentSnapshot lastDocument = changes.get(changes.size() - 1).getDocument();
```

Finally, when users scrolls to the end of the list:

```
paginate(lastDocument, 5);
```

And `onDocumentAdded()` will take care of it. Be carfure **NOT** to use `startAt()` because it **will not execlude the last one** (that already at the end of your list, and will duplicate it).