# Represent firestore data into List view

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to android development and I am making an app which will read data from firestore and will present it in list view.
My firestore has 16 collections and each collection will have random document Id and each document will have 2 fields -"Title" and "Description"
My idea is that I will create 2 global arrays one of title and one of decription
and a function will add  field of document to global_title ARRAY and  field to global_desc ARRAY
and then I will use arrayAdapter to show them in list view but I am confused on how should I setup that function so that it will search all document from given collection and takes all the field and store it in global array.
Can someone guide me out over this?
here is my database image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPdCq.png)

I want to get Title,notification and documentId(which is random here) and I want to present this data in list with rows as:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9ZMH.png)
and against title it will display the title of all documents present in my collection and same for description.
and when I select radio button for that row and press del button that will delete that document.
@AlexMamo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load batches of data in a recycler view using firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46795445/how-to-load-batches-of-data-in-a-recycler-view-using-firestore)

Comment: Instead of describing how your database looks like, please edit your question and add a screenshot of it. Please also indicate the exact data you want to get.  Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added Images